# Is it possible to create a daemon-like process in Blackberry?

Tags: blackberry, daemon

I am curious to know whether it is possible to write a regular blackberry UI application that can create a daemon process that:

1. Runs in the background
2. It has no UI and no icon in the task list which user can switch to
3. It can interact with the main application (with UI) in a secure way

Is this at all possible? If yes what is the best way to write such an app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. You can, for example, create your background application by inherting from `Application` and then use [`RuntimeStore`](http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/17952/Storing_objects_nonpersistently_1219788_11.jsp) to communicate with the UI application.